# How to confirm a db row deletion with jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

I use this jQuery UI for confirmation dialog for logout:

```
$(function() {
  $("#opener").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
            "Logout": function() 
            {
             location = "logout.php";
            },
            Cancel: function() 
            {
             $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
      }
    });
  });
});

<img src="cross.png" border="0" alt="Logout" id="opener" />
<div id="dialog" title="Logout">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>
logout?
</p></div>
```

It works fine, but:

I have a table that all rows come from database. Each row has a cross icon linked to `?action=delete&id=x`
X is the row id in database.
when creating a table with `foreach()` data fetched from db, I have this in a column of each row to confirm row deletion:

```
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?action=delete&amp;id=<?=$user['id']?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')">
<img src="cross.png" width="16" height="16" alt= "Delete" border="0" />
</a>
```

I want to migrate with jQuery dialog. After confirm, how to set location with something like blah.php?action=delete&id=94

94 is id of the row in database. In sample above redirecting to just logout.php is easy, but: 
1) How to pass the value of $user['id'] to append it to the location url? 
2) As this is in foreach() how to avoid the same jQuery UI function again and again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would advise, using a basic example.

My Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mafnxaxq/

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
  <img src="cross.png" border="0" alt="Logout" id="opener" />
</div>
<div class="content">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Data</th>
        <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Data Row 1</td>
        <td class="actions">
          <span data-id="1" class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus remove" title="Delete"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Data Row 2</td>
        <td class="actions">
          <span data-id="2" class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus remove" title="Delete"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Data Row 3</td>
        <td class="actions">
          <span data-id="3" class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus remove" title="Delete"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Data Row 4</td>
        <td class="actions">
          <span data-id="4" class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus remove" title="Delete"></span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="dialog">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span> Are you sure?
  </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 400,
    modal: true
  });

  $("#opener").click(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "buttons", [{
      text: "Logout",
      click: function() {
        location = "logout.php";
      }
    }, {
      text: "Cancel",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]);
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Logout");
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });

  $(".remove").click(function() {
    var rowId = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "buttons", [{
      text: "Delete",
      click: function() {
        window.location.href = "<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?action=delete&id=" + rowId;
      }
    }, {
      text: "Cancel",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]);
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Confirm Delete");
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

Here you can see how we use the same Dialog for multiple actions. When we click a specific button, we can change the resulting buttons, title, and functions.

Comment: Thanks. I have a form with several independent datePicker (not start/end datePicker fields), if I am correct I need to have a separate datePicker js code for each of them, I am wondering if a trick is possible to have one datePicker js code for all of those fields with separate date chosen? @Twisty

Comment: @user4271704 it would be similar to what's done here. The answer could be a bit lengthy, but yes, you can assign `id` and `class` attributes to each field. For example, `<input type="text" id="date_1" class="datepick" />`, and then use a selector that would encompass all of them: `$(".datepick").datepicker();` or `$("input[id^='date_']").datepicker();`. This would contain all the options you want for each generally. You can then go back using unique selectors to add specific options for each. There are ways to improve this too.

Comment: sorry, it is working fine now, but as I have the code in a js file, it cannot interprete ```$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']``` and I am redirected to ```%3C?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?action=delete&id=94``` is there a way to solve it without hardcoding file name? @Twisty

Comment: plus previous comment, how can I have a separate message for deletion than logout? @Twisty

Comment: @user4271704 capture `window.location` like `var SELF = window.location;` and then you can use it in JS like `window.location.href = SELF + "?action=delete&id=" + rowId`.

Comment: @user4271704 yes, you can change the message in a number of different ways. Consider this: `<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span><span id="messageText"></span></p>` and I will let you work out the rest.

Comment: with this dialog message change what changes I have to do in js? @Twisty?

Comment: @user4271704 as I said, I am going to let you work that out for yourself. Look at my answer and you should be able to extrapolate what you need to do. Try it out, take a stab at it. If you are unable to find workable solution, search for other examples on SO or post a new question.

Comment: @user4271704 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453976/confirm-form-submit-with-jquery-ui/39458878

Comment: @user4271704 "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish, and you feed him for a lifetime." If you're going to continue to use jQuery in your site, you should learn how to use jQuery in your site. You seem to not want to even try to work it out for yourself. So here is your fish, in the click functions, you can use: `$("#messageText").html("Do you want to Logout?");` This will change the message text in the dialog. You would then use this same code in your other click functions with a different string.

Comment: Many thanks. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/nimasdj/xj3sLz0n/1/ why is it not working properly? appreciate your advice. @Twisty

Comment: @user4271704 you had removed the `div`. See https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/j4561d2s/

Comment: I highly appreciate that you wanted to teach me fishing. this is just 2 days that I am using jQuery+UI, and yesterday bought the books to learn. I need time to learn fishing. Many thanks again for all kind helps. @Twisty