# confirm form submit with jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-ui

I'm trying to confirm a submit form that is created using ruby on rails, but before submitting I have a condition that open a confirm popup asking if the user really wants to do it. This is working with the default confirm browser box. But now i'm trying to do it with Jquery UI but it's not working. How can I return true or false using jquery ui ?

If the user click "yes" the form should be submitted, if "no" it should just close

this is my jquery ui function:

```
  function confirm(message, callback) {
    $('body').append('<div id="confirm" style="display:none">'+message+'</div>');
    $( "#confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      title: 'Confirm',
      zIndex: 99999999,
      modal: true,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: "Yes",
          click: function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
              callback.apply();
            }

          }
        },{
          text: "No",
          click: function() { $(this).dialog("close");}
        }
      ],
      close: function(event, ui) {
        $('#confirm').remove();
      }
    });
  }
```

And my submit function:

```
     $('form').submit(function(){

          <% @meetings.each do |mt| %>

       ...

          <%# cvalue_starthour.value %>

          $meeting_dates = [];

     ...

          $.each($meeting_dates, function (index, value) {
            $.each($test, function (index2, value2) {
);

              if (value.priority == "<%= l(:default_priority_trivial) %>" || "<%= l(:default_priority_minor) %>" || "<%= l(:default_priority_major) %>") {

                if ((value.date == value2.date) && (value.time == value2.time)) {
                  message = confirm("Are you sure?");


                }
              }
            });
          });


          <%      end %>


          <%  end %>

          if (message) {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        });


      });
```

Comment: Your function does not return anything. `message` is `null` or empty in either case.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the way that the browser handles it's own alert, confirm, and prompt versus self generated dialogs. You need to add in a try/catch sort of scenario.

I created the following a bit back to address this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7kp46r22/3/

This uses `$.deferred()` and `$.when()` to wait for the user to make a selection before returning the results or executing any callbacks.

For your application, this might look like:

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/wtogu9cu/

**HTML**

```
<form id="myForm">
  Submit Form:
  <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
function ui_confirm(message, callback) {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  var dialog = $("<div>", {
      id: "confirm"
    })
    .html(message)
    .appendTo($("body"))
    .data("selection", false)
    .dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      resizable: false,
      title: 'Confirm',
      zIndex: 99999999,
      modal: true,
      buttons: [{
        text: "Yes",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          dfd.resolve(true);
          if ($.isFunction(callback)) {
            callback.apply();
          }
        }
      }, {
        text: "No",
        click: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          dfd.resolve(false);
        }
      }],
      close: function(event, ui) {
        $('#confirm').remove();
      }
    });
  dialog.dialog("open");
  return dfd.promise();
}
$(function() {
  $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // your code

    $.when(ui_confirm("Are you sure?")).done(function(val) {
      if (val) {
        console.log("Submit the form.");
        $('#myForm')[0].submit();
      } else {
        console.log("Do not submit the form.");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: with that code, the function is not stopping when I click submit, it submits and then appears the confirm form. because I'm submitting with rails ajax, but before submitting I'm doing this validation in js

Comment: @terrorista something does not add up there. Since the code has been executed and sent to the browser, it's being executed client side. Thus the `e.preventDefault()` should prevent the browser from submitting the data to the server until the form element is submitted again programmatically. Maybe I am missing something?