# jQuery Confirmation Dialog Modal - Unable to Submit Form Sucessfully

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, forms, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a sample code block below which consists of a simple bootstrap form whereby I am using a jqueryUI Modal Dialog as a replacement for the basic javascript confirmation window.

When i submit the form by clicking the submit button, the jqueryUI modal window does popup without any issues.

If;

I click "No" - I get all 3 console.log messages i.e.

- 1-Confirmation_In_Progress
- 4-Confirmation_Cancelled
- 5-Confirmation_Cancelled

If;

I click "Yes" - I get all 3 console.log messages i.e.

- 1-Confirmation_In_Progress
- 2-Confirmation_AboutTo
- 3-Confirmation_Done

Therefore I conclude the jquery code must be working to some extent BUT the form values dont seem to be posted.

I have tried various methods to submit the form as seen below.
Any idea what is wrong with my jquery form submission ?

The form code is below;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title> Simple BootStrap Form -  jQuery UI Modal Dialog as Confirmation Box </title>
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans"                                              rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"              media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"             rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">    
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"                                    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


 <!-- CSS -->
 <style>

 .customColor    { background: darkturquoise; } 
 .jqDialogAdjust { float: left; margin: 2px 2px 0 0; }  
 .no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { display: none }

 </style>     


 </head>
 <!-- HTML -->
 <body>

 <div class="container">
 <br><br>
   <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> HOME </a>
 <br><br>

 <?php
 if ( isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ) {

   echo "<br>"."<br>";
   echo "Name :".$_POST['name']."<br>";
   echo "Email :".$_POST['email']."<br>";

 } else { 

 ?>  

 <form id="simpleform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post"  >

 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
 </div>

 <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default"  name="submit_btn" id="submit_btn"  value="submit_btn" >Submit</button>

 </form>

 <div id="confirmdialog" title="Confirmation Required"></div>

 <?php } ?>
 </div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"                                                    type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"                                                 type="text/javascript"></script>    
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"                            type="text/javascript">  </script>         

 <script type="text/javascript" >    


  $(document).ready(function(){


      $("#submit_btn").click(function(event){  

      console.log('1-Confirmation_In_Progress');

      event.preventDefault();      
      var $target = $( event.target );    
      var message = 'Proceed With Action?';
      var icon = '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert jqDialogAdjust" ></span>';

      $('#confirmdialog').html('<p>' + icon + message + '</p>');

      $("#confirmdialog").dialog({
          autoOpen : false,
          modal : true,
          height: 170,
          width: 340,
          resizable: false,
          draggable:false,
          closeOnEscape: true,
          title : " :: Confirmation Required :: ",             
          classes: {
                        "ui-dialog-titlebar": "ui-corner-all customColor"                          
                    },
          dialogClass: "no-close",         
          buttons: [{
                        text : "Yes",                           
                        click : function() {                                    
                                  console.log('2-Confirmation_AboutTo'); 
                                  //die;                                  
                                $target.closest("form").submit();
                                //$('form#simpleform').submit();
                                  console.log('3-Confirmation_Done');                          
                                $(this).dialog("close");                               
                        }                              
                    },                        
                    {
                        text : "No",
                        click : function() {
                                  console.log('4-Confirmation_Cancelled');
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                                  console.log('5-Confirmation_Cancelled');
                        }
                    }]   



      });   // end of confirmdialog.dialog  

    $('#confirmdialog').dialog('open');      

    }); // end of submit_btn.click(function(event)    

  }); // end jQuery Document Ready

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

The above code block was put together by refering to various snippets here on StackOverFlow but somehow I just cant get the form to submit. If i remove the jquery lines and use a basic javascript confirm window - the form submits properly.

Comment: I suspect `$(event.target).closest()` is not selecting the form. Any errors or alerts in Console?

Comment: @Twisty- I click "Yes" - I get all 3 console.log messages i.e.

1-Confirmation_In_Progress
2-Confirmation_AboutTo
3-Confirmation_Done

Comment: @Twisty - Replacing the Javascript Confirmation box ( return confirm ()) seems quite a hassle in jQuery. WHat do you use ?

Comment: There is no way to *replace* since the browser generated the dialog window itself. I have already worked this out; it's not exactly fun. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453976/confirm-form-submit-with-jquery-ui *I created the following a bit back to address this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/7kp46r22/3/

This uses `$.Deferred` and `$when()` to wait for the user to make a selection before returning the results or executing any callbacks.*

Comment: @Twisty - Noted. I have an update. Looks like my issue  was if ( isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ). With jQuery, the submit button is not sent when the form is posted. If i change the if condition to the name or email, the jquery form submission works !

Comment: Makes sense. I was not looking at the PHP, but that would make sense. Adding the `name` attribute to the submit button would include it in the received data.

Comment: The button ( as in the code above ) already has name="submit_btn" . Apparently bcos of this successful-control thingy, the button is not auto-included in the jquery form submission - which i have yet  to learn how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above to user Twisty, looks like my problem was this line;

```
  if ( isset($_POST['submit_btn']) ) {

      echo "<br>"."<br>";
      echo "Name :".$_POST['name']."<br>";
      echo "Email :".$_POST['email']."<br>";

  }
```

Jquery form submission does not include the button names and values into the post superglobal. Changing the if to either 'name' or 'email' allowed the post values to appear.

All these form submissions work as long as the if condition is NOT based on the button name/value.

```
 $target.closest("form").submit();                                      
 $('form[name="simpleform"]').submit();                                    
 $('form#simpleform').submit();
 document.forms["simpleform"].submit();
 document.getElementById("simpleform").submit()
 $('#simpleform').submit();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I created a test fiddle and tried to replicate the issue. I could not. It might be best to define your Dialog first and then the events.

For Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/f0sa5nmL/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#confirmdialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 170,
    width: 340,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    classes: {
      "ui-dialog-titlebar": "ui-corner-all customColor"
    },
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    buttons: [{
      text: "Yes",
      click: function() {
        console.log('2-Confirmation_AboutTo');
        $("#simpleform").submit();
        console.log('3-Confirmation_Done');
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }, {
      text: "No",
      click: function() {
        console.log("4-Confirmation_Cancelled");
        $(this).dialog("close");
        console.log("5-Confirmation_Cancelled");
      }
    }]
  });

  $("#submit_btn").click(function(event) {
    console.log("1-Confirmation_In_Progress");
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#confirmdialog").dialog("open");
  });
});
```

If I choose No, I get:

```
1-Confirmation_In_Progress
4-Confirmation_Cancelled
5-Confirmation_Cancelled
```

The form does not submit and the dialog closes. If I choose Yes, I get:

```
1-Confirmation_In_Progress
2-Confirmation_AboutTo
3-Confirmation_Done
```

The form then attempts to submit (and fails since it can't submit itself to itself in the fiddle.).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Roger that @Twisty. Will keep at it.