# CKEditor inline plugin confirmation dialog before save

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, ckeditor

In my project, we make ckeditor inline editing like [this](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/inline.html).
After finishing my edit, I click out to save my modification.
then the event `blur` is fired, editor instance loses the input focus and makes a ajax call to save the modification in database.

My issue is how to add a confirmation dialog (with two buttons, `yes` to save and `cancel` to stay in editor input) before the event `blur` is fired ? I don't want lose the toolbars when confirmation dialog is opend.

Also I want to know if there is a event will be fired before the disappearance of toolbars.

Thank you for any suggestions !

Comment: Possibly similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453976/confirm-form-submit-with-jquery-ui

Comment: @Twisty Thank you for your answer. This example is great but it's not suitable for my case because my case has a relation with CKeditor. I want to find the ckeditor's event to fire my confirm dialog.

Comment: @Twisty maybe a exist ckeditor plugin ?